# TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object, when time series mungling

Tags: python, pandas

Have a time series ts (dataframe.to_dict())

```
{'latitude': {Timestamp('2014-10-20 15:21:56.571000'): 48.145553900000003,
  Timestamp('2014-10-20 15:24:00.789000'): 48.145584300000003,
  Timestamp('2014-10-20 15:26:00.911000'): 48.145497599999999,
  Timestamp('2014-10-20 15:33:57.764000'): 48.145548699999999,
  Timestamp('2014-10-20 15:36:45.760000'): 48.145454999999998},
  'longitude': {Timestamp('2014-10-20 15:21:56.571000'): 11.578263,
  Timestamp('2014-10-20 15:24:00.789000'): 11.5783685,
  Timestamp('2014-10-20 15:26:00.911000'): 11.578193499999999,
  Timestamp('2014-10-20 15:33:57.764000'): 11.5782843,
  Timestamp('2014-10-20 15:36:45.760000'): 11.5783164},
  'speed': {Timestamp('2014-10-20 15:21:56.571000'): 0.0,
  Timestamp('2014-10-20 15:24:00.789000'): 0.0,
  Timestamp('2014-10-20 15:26:00.911000'): 0.0,
  Timestamp('2014-10-20 15:33:57.764000'): 0.0,
  Timestamp('2014-10-20 15:36:45.760000'): 0.0}}
```

and a customized aggregation function (example)

```
def my_func(group):
    first_latitude = group['latitude'].sort_index().head(1).values[0]
    last_longitude = group['longitude'].sort_index().tail(1).values[0]
    return first_latitude - last_longitude
```

want to aggregate time series with customized function by 10 min, so

```
ts.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='10Min')).apply(my_func)
```

then instead of correct result, it gives me error

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object
```

What does this error say ? How could I write the code correctly ? thx a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to `agg` (aggregate), not `apply`, as for each of your group, you want 1 returning value:

```
In [185]:

print ts.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='10Min')).agg(my_func)
                      latitude  longitude      speed
2014-10-20 15:20:00  36.567360  36.567360  36.567360
2014-10-20 15:30:00  36.567232  36.567232  36.567232
```

Answer (score 0):

`pd.DataFrame()` might be what you are looking for. It allows you to parse two dimensional dictionaries (or anything, really with a tabular structure).
Here is the documentation for the function:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame